# Using bash functions in snakemake

Tags: bash, function, download, snakemake

I am trying to download some files with snakemake. The files (http://snpeff.sourceforge.net/SnpSift.html#dbNSFP) I would like to download are on a google site/drive and my usual wget approach does not work. I found a bash function that does the job (https://www.zachpfeffer.com/single-post/wget-a-Google-Drive-file):

```
function gdrive_download () {  CONFIRM=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=$1" -O- | sed -rn 's/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p')  wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$CONFIRM&id=$1" -O $2  rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt }

gdrive_download 120aPYqveqPx6jtssMEnLoqY0kCgVdR2fgMpb8FhFNHo test.txt
```

I have tested this function with my ids in a plain bash script and was able to download all the files. To add a bit to the complexity, I **must** use a workplace template, and incorporate the function into it.

```
rule dl: 
    params:
        url = 'ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/clinvar/vcf_{genome}/{afile}'
    output:
        'data/{genome}/{afile}'
    params:
        id1 = '0B7Ms5xMSFMYlOTV5RllpRjNHU2s',
        f1 = 'dbNSFP.txt.gz'
    shell:
        """CONFIRM=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id={{params.id1}}" -O- | sed -rn "s/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p") && wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$CONFIRM&id={{params.id1}}" -O {{params.f1}} && rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt"""
        #'wget -c {params.url} -O {output}'

rule checksum:
    input:
        i = 'data/{genome}/{afile}'
    output:
        o = temp('tmp/{genome}/{afile}.md5')
    shell:
        'md5sum {input} > {output}'

rule file_size:
    input:
        i = 'data/{genome}/{afile}'
    output:
        o = temp('tmp/{genome}/{afile}.size')
    shell:
        'du -csh --apparent-size {input} > {output}'

rule file_info:
    """md5 checksum and file size"""
    input:
        md5 = 'tmp/{genome}/{afile}.md5',
        s = 'tmp/{genome}/{afile}.size'
    output:
        o = temp('tmp/{genome}/info/{afile}.csv')
    run:
        with open(input.md5) as f:
            md5, fp = f.readline().strip().split()
        with open(input.s) as f:
            size = f.readline().split()[0]
        with open(output.o, 'w') as fout:
            print('filepath,size,md5', file=fout)
            print(f"{fp},{size},{md5}", file=fout)

rule manifest:
    input:
        expand('tmp/{genome}/info/{suffix}.csv', genome=('GRCh37','GRCh38'), suffix=('dbNSFP.txt.gz', 'dbNSFP.txt.gz.tbi'))
        #expand('tmp/{genome}/info/SnpSift{suffix}.csv', genome=('GRCh37','GRCh38'), suffix=('dbNSFP.txt.gz', 'dbNSFP.txt.gz.tbi'))
    output:
        o = 'MANIFEST.csv'
    run:
        pd.concat([pd.read_csv(afile) for afile in input]).to_csv(output.o, index=False)
```

There are four downloadable files for which I have ids (I only show one in params), however I don't know how to call the bash functions as written by ZPfeffer for all the ids I have with snakemake. Additionally, when I run this script, there are several errors, the most pressing being

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 31: unterminated `s' command
```

I am far from a snakemake expert, any assistance on how to modify my script to a) call the functions with 4 different ids, b) remove the sed error, and c) verify whether this is the correct url format (currently url = 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export/{afile}) will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I "solved" it:

```
import pandas as pd

rule dl: 
    output:
        'data/{genome}/{afile}'
    shell:
        "sh download_snpsift.sh"

rule checksum:
    input:
        i = 'data/{genome}/{afile}'
    output:
        o = temp('tmp/{genome}/{afile}.md5')
    shell:
        'md5sum {input} > {output}'

rule file_size:
    input:
        i = 'data/{genome}/{afile}'
    output:
        o = temp('tmp/{genome}/{afile}.size')
    shell:
        'du -csh --apparent-size {input} > {output}'

rule file_info:
    """md5 checksum and file size"""
    input:
        md5 = 'tmp/{genome}/{afile}.md5',
        s = 'tmp/{genome}/{afile}.size'
    output:
        o = temp('tmp/{genome}/info/{afile}.csv')
    run:
        with open(input.md5) as f:
            md5, fp = f.readline().strip().split()
        with open(input.s) as f:
            size = f.readline().split()[0]
        with open(output.o, 'w') as fout:
            print('filepath,size,md5', file=fout)
            print(f"{fp},{size},{md5}", file=fout)

rule manifest:
    input:
        expand('tmp/{genome}/info/{suffix}.csv', genome=('GRCh37','GRCh38'), suffix=('dbNSFP.txt.gz', 'dbNSFP.txt.gz.tbi'))
    output:
        o = 'MANIFEST.csv'
    run:
        pd.concat([pd.read_csv(afile) for afile in input]).to_csv(output.o, index=False)
```

And here is the bash script.

```
function gdrive_download () {
 CONFIRM=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=$1" -O- | sed -rn 's/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p')
 wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$CONFIRM&id=$1" -O $2
 rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt
}

gdrive_download 0B7Ms5xMSFMYlSTY5dDJjcHVRZ3M data/GRCh37/dbNSFP.txt.gz
gdrive_download 0B7Ms5xMSFMYlOTV5RllpRjNHU2s data/GRCh37/dbNSFP.txt.gz.tbi

gdrive_download 0B7Ms5xMSFMYlbTZodjlGUDZnTGc data/GRCh38/dbNSFP.txt.gz
gdrive_download 0B7Ms5xMSFMYlNVBJdFA5cFZRYkE data/GRCh38/dbNSFP.txt.gz.tbi
```

Answer (score 3):

You would want to use [raw string literal](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) so that snakemake doesn't escape special characters, such as backslash in `sed` command. For example (notice `r` in front of shell command):

```
rule foo:
   shell: 
       r"sed d\s\"
```

You could use [`--printshellcmds` or `-p`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#OUTPUT) to see how exactly `shell:` commands get resolved by snakemake.

Comment: Thank you MG for the sed info, but it only addressed 1/3 of my question. I was still unable to figure out how to use the ids as a function call within snakemake, so I cheated and called a bash script to download the files in the dl rule.